# Why does this code set the text to undefined?

Tags: javascript

Here is my JS function that sets the text to the variables. And how assign what Pokémon the player has.

```
function setStats() {
// Sets up stats based on Pokemon
if (computerPokemon === 'Pikachu') {
    var computerAttack = 30;
    var computerUlt = 60; // Does damage
    var computerHealth = 50;
    var computerSpeed = 20;
    var computerAgility = 10;
}

if (playerPokemon === 'Ho-Oh') {
    var playerAttack = 70;
    var playerUlt = 10; // Buffs HP
    var playerHealth = 80;
    var playerSpeed = 35;
    var playerAgility = 12;
}

document.getElementById("pHP").innerHTML = 'Health: ' + playerHealth;
document.getElementById("pSpeed").innerHTML = 'Speed: ' + playerSpeed;
document.getElementById("pAgility").innerHTML = 'Agility: ' + playerAgility; 
}

function startGame() {
// Player Pokemon Selector
var playerPokemonArray = ["Ho-Oh","Venusaur","Weedle"];
var playerPokemonArrayRandom =  Math.floor((Math.random() * playerPokemonArray.length));
var playerPokemon = playerPokemonArray[playerPokemonArrayRandom];
document.getElementById("playerPokemon").innerHTML = 'Your Pokemon is: '     + playerPokemon;

// Computer Pokemon Selector
var computerPokemonArray = ["Pikachu","Charmander","Diglett"];
var computerPokemonArrayRandom =  Math.floor((Math.random() * computerPokemonArray.length));
var computerPokemon = computerPokemonArray[computerPokemonArrayRandom];
document.getElementById("computerPokemon").innerHTML = 'The Computer\'s Pokemon is: ' + computerPokemon;
```

When I run this code it sets the text of my stats paragraphs to undefined. Even though the variables are set depending on what Pokémon they were given.

I've tried changing my code around but nothing worked.

Comment: Needs more [mcve].

Comment: @Melpomene my problem is in that code sorry. I believe cutting down this code will make it harder for people to see where the problem may originate from

Comment: Your code doesn't even compile (unmatched `{`).

Comment: The various player variables will be undefined unless the Pokemon is Ho-Oh.

Comment: @DavidConrad aware of that. I kept running the code until it was Ho-Oh. Still didn't work. I think the problem might be somewhere with the if statements and the pokemon selector

Comment: i think the point melpomene was making is that the code shown has been cut down too much. The `startGame()` function shown is incomplete (no closing `}`), and you don't show how either function is called. Calling `startGame()` would result in a ReferenceError *before* it gets to try to set the `.innerHTML`, because the variables in its `if` conditions are defined locally in the other function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is setting the stat variables from within the `setStats()` function, and you are trying to access them from `startGame()`. Javascript is a lexical scoped language. Since you are setting the variables from withink the function, only that function can access the variables. You can fix this by moving the variables into the global scope.

(Also, you are never calling the function `setStats()`

Comment: Which variables are you talking about specifically? Looks to me like the problem is the other way around, that `setStats()` is trying to access variables from `startGame()` (in its if conditions). The variables defined within `setStats()` aren't used outside it.

Comment: that's right it depends on scope in global scope code 'acts' different than in local scope and getting undefined means that you have part of code in the wrong scope